# how can I prevent Excel 2003 from checking every hyperlink in a document when the document opens?

Tags: excel-2003

I have a spreadsheet that has several worksheets, each containing a hundred or so hyperlinks to other documents on our network (`file:////server/share/path/to/spreadsheet.xls`). Opening these files within Excel 2003 takes a very long time, compared to how long it takes to open in 2007 or 2010. I took a look in Task Manager at the network tab to see what was going on when these files are opened and noticed a lot of steady network traffic while the file was opening, and as soon as the spreadsheet finally displayed on the screen, the network traffic dropped down to almost nothing. As I removed some of those links, the file would open faster, until I finally got rid of all the links and the file opened almost as fast as any other normal spreadsheet. Is there a way to prevent Excel from doing whatever it's doing with those links when the file first opens?

Comment: what about holding the shift key down while opening the file ?

Comment: Sadly, no. Takes just as long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a programming-related forum so:

```
 Workbooks.Open AFile, False
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819.aspx

Comment: This being a programming forum, that would be the right answer. Guess I asked in the wrong place. Is there a forum for a more general, non-programming question like this?

Comment: Hi @mounty, you can try http://superuser.com, but in this particular case, i do not think you will have much luck.